# How to make a function that changes the property of an instance?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a protocol, structure and instances + protocol and class, which should change the instances of the structure:

```
protocol Cars {

    var car: String { get set }
    var accesories: [String] { get set }
}

struct Car: Cars {

    var car: String
    var accesories: [String]
}


var carOne = Car(car: "Car One", accesories: ["accessoryOne", "accessoryTwo"])
var carTwo = Car(car: "Car Two", accesories: ["accessoryTwo"])

protocol Dealership {

    static var cars: [Car] { get set }

    static func addAccesories(add: [String])
}
```

Next, in `DealershipOne` I want to make a `func addAccesories` that will add an array of strings to the instance property, I try do it this way and some other ways, but I get the error ***Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: '$0' is a 'let' constant.***

```
class DealershipOne: Dealership {

    static var cars = [carOne, carTwo]

    static func addAccesories(add: [String]) {
        cars.forEach{ $0.accesories.append(contentsOf: add) } // ERROR

    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Where's the `section`?

Comment: Oh sorry, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add new value to direct iterated objects. $0 is a let object so you can not add value.

A solution to use index and update the value.

````
cars.indices.forEach{ cars[$0].accesories.append(contentsOf: add) }```
````

Comment: Offsets aren’t the same as indices. For some collection types, this will crash, and it’s easy to forget when. I suggest always avoiding to subscript using an “offset” as provided by `enumerated`

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous closure parameter (`$0`) within your `forEach` loop is an immutable copy of a car from the `cars` you’re trying to iterate.

You could make a mutable copy with `var car = $0`, but even that won’t help, because you would be mutating the copy, and not the actual cars in the static `cars` array.

If you would like to keep using struct to model your cars, then the only way to modify properties of those cars within the array is to get an l-value (in c++ lingo) via assignment through a subscript:

```
func add(accessories: [String]) {
    for i in cars.insides {
        cars[i].accessories += accessories
    }
}
```

(I also made some minor tweaks to make this more idiomatic, such as t changing the function name, and using the `+=` operator for arrays instead of `Array.append(contentsOf:)`)